# MUI seems to shift my entire window/container to the right. How do I fix this?

Tags: css, material-ui

When resizing my window, I noticed it would cut the right side off. Also when looking at it head on the entire page is shifted to the right a bit. I couldn't find any fix for this online nor by my findings with MUI or my application. If you know why this is happening I would love the help.

Here is my file;

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Container } from '@mui/system';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Home = () => {

  return (
    <>

      <Container sx={{ bgcolor: 'teal'}}>
        <Typography
        display={'flex'}
        height={'300px'}
        justifyContent={'center'}
        alignItems={'center'}
        fontWeight={'700'}
        fontSize={'larger'}
        >
          This is text.
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    
    
    </>
  );
};
```

[Img of window with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pseAT.png)

I thought I had some lone Margin/Padding lying around somewhere, but this was not the case.